# La mejor forma de respaldar una tabla por periodos

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla (`tabla_1`) que es editada constantemente con determinados valores y deseo poder guardar un registro consultable de estos mismos datos de su estado en periodos de tiempo pasado.

Estoy considerando crear una segunda tabla (`tabla_periodos`) y guardar los cientos de usuarios con un campo adicional que corresponda al periodo como un identificador.

Algo como:

```
{tabla_periodos}
juan,  activo,   juan@1.com,  periodo1 
pedro, inactivo, pedro@1.com, periodo1
juan,  inactivo, juan@2.com,  periodo2 
pedro, inactivo, pedro@2.com, periodo2
```

Pero siento que estaría saturando la tabla y creo que puede existir mejores formas de tener un registro en mi base, ¿alguna sugerencia que puedan darme quienes tengan mas experiencia en este tema?

Comment: Pienso que lo que necesitas es cambiar la estructura, con una tabla de usuarios (pedro, juan...) relacionado a otra tabla en el que se harán INSERT de todos los movimientos, en vez de hacer UPDATE. Obviamente con las respectivas formas de indexado (id, fecha, etc...) y de esta forma consultas los movimientos en cualquier momento del tiempo.

Comment: Te dieron respuestas, que a mi entender no son del todo correctas. Que vas a guardar en la otra tabla? igual esta pregunta roza en ser basada en opiniones. No hay una unica forma de hacer, ni una unica respuesta.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es buena idea crear una nueva tabla y que sea alimentada por medio de un trigger al insertar y actualizar en la tabla principal, tener en cuenta el join.

No se preocupe por la cantidad de datos, en lugar de eso analizar como optimizarla. Además, el hecho que esté almacenado no implica mucho, sino la consulta y manipulación de estos datos.

También se debe tener en cuenta cada cuanto se va a purgar la tabla, o eliminar los datos de un cierto periodo hacia atrás, por ejemplo, que el sistema automáticamente elimine los datos inferiores a uno o 2 años.

En el trigger guardar sólo los datos modificados en json. Si necesita ayuda con el trigger me avisa.

Comment: sería bueno que agregues el ejemplo del trigger que mencionas para mejorar tu respuesta

Comment: muchas gracias me tranquiliza un poco estava preocupado por saturar de mas una tabla :)